# catch different errors from dplyr data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a situation where my data frame can contain different errors and I want to catch both cases with an `if` statement afterwards.

**Situtation 1:**
the data frame contains `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
attach(iris)

data <- iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length >=7.9)
   sepal_slope <- data %>% group_by(Species) %>%
   do(fit = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, .)) %>%
    summarise(sepal_slope = coef(fit)[2])
```

this is FALSE:

```
 nrow(sepal_slope) == 0
 # FALSE
```

`is.na` is TRUE here as intended

```
is.na(sepal_slope)
# TRUE
```

**Situation 2:** the data frame is empty

```
  data <- iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length >=12)
  sepal_slope <- data %>% group_by(Species) %>%
   do(fit = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, .)) %>%
   summarise(sepal_slope = coef(fit)[2])
```

now this is TRUE as intended:

```
nrow(sepal_slope) == 0
# TRUE
```

but this produces an error:

```
is.na(sepal_slope)
# sepal_slope
```

So I cannot use

```
if(nrow(sepal_slope) == 0 | is.na(sepal_slope)) sepal_slope <- 5
# Error in if (nrow(sepal_slope) == 0 | is.na(sepal_slope))    sepal_slope <- 5 : 
  argument is of length zero
```

How can I catch both situations in one if statement

Of course the case where sepal_slope contains a num value should be handled, if should yield TRUE here by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you coerce your `sepal_slope` to `numeric` both cases will respond as `TRUE` to `is.na`.

```
if(is.na(as.numeric(unlist(sepal_slope))[1])) sepal_slope <- 5
```